# configuration.setLocale(locale) doesn't work with AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode

Tags: android, setlocale, android-10.0, android-dark-theme

If I set darkmode with `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` and the system is not dark, then `Configuration.setLocale` doesn't work.
I change the locale, for example, from `En` to `It`, all the strings are still displayed in the system language.

There are no problems if I set the same NightMode of the system (Android 10).
The same problem with android 9 or less: if I set darkmode in my app and I change the context language, the activity displays text based on the language of the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kotlin solution

```
override fun applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration: Configuration?) {
    overrideConfiguration?.let {
        val uiMode = it.uiMode
        it.setTo(baseContext.resources.configuration)
        it.uiMode = uiMode
    }
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration)
}
```

Java solution

```
@Override
public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
    if (overrideConfiguration != null) {
        int uiMode = overrideConfiguration.uiMode;
        overrideConfiguration.setTo(getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
        overrideConfiguration.uiMode = uiMode;
    }
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
}
```

Comment: This stopped working after `1.2.0-alpha02` for Android 6.0.1 API 23, even though they said it's fixed in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140602653 :/